# XML Type Provider Create New XML Object Fails

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

I'm trying to combine two `XmlDocument.xml`s for WebAPI 2.0 documentation. But when I do the below code it returns `< /doc>` with no errors. It looks like I'm doing everything right, so I'm a bit confused. Where the `printf` statement is, that is where it is failing with the result value. Before and after the code seems to work flawlessly.

```
#r "../packages/FSharp.Data.2.2.5/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll"
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"
open FSharp.Data
open System.IO

// Define your library scripting code here

let seedPath = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "../../FieldOps/bin"
let outFile = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "../../FieldOps/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml"

type XmlDocument = XmlProvider<"""<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly><name>lala</name></assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="">
            <summary>lala</summary>
            <param name="">lala</param>
            <param name="">lala</param>
            <returns>lala</returns>
        </member>
        <member name=""></member>
    </members>
</doc>
""">

let xmlPaths =
    [
        "../bin/Release"
    ]

let seed = XmlDocument.Load(Path.Combine(seedPath, "XmlDocument.xml"))
let addFile path = Path.Combine(path, "XmlDocument.XML")
let loadXmlDoc (path: string) = XmlDocument.Load(path)
let joinXmlDocuments (acc: XmlDocument.Doc) path =
    let doc = (addFile >> loadXmlDoc) path
    let members = Array.append acc.Members doc.Members
    let result = new XmlDocument.Doc(acc.Assembly, members)
    printf "result -------------------  %A  --------------------" result
    result

let joinedDocs =
    xmlPaths
    |> List.fold (joinXmlDocuments) seed

let xml = joinedDocs.XElement.ToString()
File.WriteAllText(outFile, xml)
```

Comment: There isn't any error. It just comes back with a `< /doc>` instead of all the data.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** → I think I know why it has the problem. Probably because they are immutable so you need to create a new one. But, how to easily do that, I don't know.

It appears that the `XmlProvider` doesn't recognize it's own types. Not sure what is going on exactly. But when I recreate the types from scratch it doesn't come back with the empty `< /doc>` value that I was seeing.

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
let assembly = new XmlDocument.Assembly(acc.Assembly.Name)
let members =
    Array.append acc.Members doc.Members
    |> Array.map
        (
            fun x ->
            let parameters =
                x.Params
                |> Array.map (fun x -> new XmlDocument.Param(x.Name, x.Value))
            new XmlDocument.Member(x.Name, x.Summary, parameters, x.Returns)
        )
let result = XmlDocument.Doc(assembly, members)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in F# Data 2.3.0-beta1